# Custom AutoComplete in Android

Tags: android, autocomplete, autocompletetextview

I want to display List of Contact Names with the respective phone numbers

like

---

**Vikas Patidar       <9999999999>**

---

**Rahul Patidar       <9999999999>**

---

using AutoCompleteTextView when a user type text in the mobile number field.

In default style I can only display the list of names.

Can anyone please tell me how can I implement this so that when a user select any item in list and I can display number of that in Mobile number field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need use adapter for this task. For example, with [SimpleAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html):

```
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(context, list, R.id.row_layout, new String[] { "Name", "Phone" }, new int[] { R.id.name, R.id.phone });
autoCompleteField.setAdapter(adapter);
```

For this you need make a layout XML file and list must be of type `List<? extends Map<String, ?>`. Strings in 4th parameter are keys for maps in list. Ints in 5th parameter are identifiers of components in layout file.

Or you can extend any adapter and use it. See this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html#binding) for reference.

Comment: Yes..but this displays text in the autocomplete like {name="tom" and no="1234"}.If I use onItemClickListener ,it takes cursor to start of the text field.I am working on this,Please suggest a solution