# Android AutoComplete TextBox, setting your own specific suggestions?

Tags: android, autocomplete, filtering

I have some technical problems here, for example I have an adapter for autocomplete textbox that contains this list, [ Bahrain, Belarus, Bahamas]. If I typed for example "ah", I want to display in the drop-down of autocomplete_textbox these two, [Bahrain, Bahamas], since those two contains a substring of "ah" (B"ah"amas and B"ah"rain).

Please help me, been figuring this out for a week. :(

Here's my code:

Inside onCreate() method of my main activity:

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    countries = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.countries_array);       
    textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_country);     

    TextWatcher textChecker = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)                            {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            String enteredText = textView.getText().toString();
            refreshList(enteredText);
            textView.showDropDown();
        }
    };        

    textView.addTextChangedListener(textChecker);   

}

public void refreshList(String text) {
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, fetchTop20(countries, text));
    textView.setThreshold(1);
    textView.setAdapter(adapter);
}



public List<String> fetchTop20(String[] countries, String strToFind){


     List<String> arrList_countries =  Arrays.asList(countries);
     List<String> arrList_strTop20 = new ArrayList<String>();

     int ctrToTwenty = 0;
     for(String currCountry: arrList_countries)
     {
         if(currCountry.toLowerCase().contains(strToFind.toLowerCase()))
         {
             arrList_strTop20.add(currCountry);
             ctrToTwenty++;
         }
         if(ctrToTwenty == 20)
         {

             break;
         }           
     }
     Log.i(TAG, "strToFind: "+ strToFind);
     Log.i(TAG, "strTop20: "+arrList_strTop20);

     return arrList_strTop20;
}
```

My AutoCompleteTextBox's adapter do contains a List with [Bahamas, Bahrain] inside, but its actual suggestion contains nothing. This works if you typed "Bah"(though you should type the first letter of the word for it to display):(.

Any suggestion android experts?, also, since my code's autocomplete filtering isn't running in a separate thread, please tell me how to optimize this or show me how to thread this code for optimization. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just answering the question in the title...

[Custom AutoComplete in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891206/custom-autocomplete-in-android)

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-autocomplete.html

--

After reading the whole question posted...

Looking at the docs, it looks like the solution is to make a custom `ListAdapter` with a custom [`Filter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filter.html).

Google searching for a few seconds turned up an example of using a custom `Filter`: [Autocomplete items disappearing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246495/autocomplete-items-disappearing)

Comment: nope, I tried it but it seems that the autoComplete mechanics of android is to suggest a list of strings with a typed substring beginning with the starting letter of the word and the ff sequence of characters(i.e, "ah" will not display bahrain, but "bah" will).:(

Comment: A little warmer I guess, wait. haha.. still checking the "Autocomplete items disappearing" link you post. :D

Comment: Yep, creating a custom adapter using Filter answers my question, but you need to explore the example given link "Autocomplete items disappearing". Thanks