# How To Apply Search Operation in arraylist on word basis?

Tags: java, android

I have object arraylist,I have to apply search operation on name basis.suppose there are 5 object in list which have names if I input in searchbox "a" then result should be "arun,ashok .." all which name start by a ,but if I input "ar" then only "arun" should be result .Please 
anyone help me how this type search aplly in arraylist.

Comment: [See this tuts](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android is having AutoCompleteTextView. You have to  bind your data to textview

Here is link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html

Check this answer also [it may help full](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775316/android-autocomplete-textbox-setting-your-own-specific-suggestions)

Answer (score 0):

Use AutoCompleteTextView http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html

Answer (score 0):

[check this](http://rakhi577.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/buttons-on-list-view-with-easy-searching-in-android/) .

Here you can initialize your arraylist to the `listview_array`.